# Flag for moderator attention in purpose of post reopening

Tags: support

Is it a valid way to request a reopening for a question that is put on hold by flagging it for a moderator attention after it was properly edited (I do not have enough reputation to flag it in other way)?

Or I should do it in other way?

Also, is it a way to check, if my flag was reviewed by moderator, who it was reviewed by, and the result of the review?

**UPDATE:**

I've already edited the post to (in my opinion) be as much exact as possible (the reason of the close was "unclear what you're asking" and the question is not mine). How can I track the reopen votes status or any other progress of the reopening process? For me the question is in the same state as before which is a little embarrassing, because I cannot distinguish following:

- no attention is driven to this question and it had no reviews
- some people reviewed it but still think it should be closed

Actually, I cannot even know that the question was taken to the review...

Answer (score 4):

> Or I should do it in other way?

You should edit the post to make it a good post (on-topic, relevant, detailed etc...). This will put it in the reopen review queue, meaning it should get reopen votes.

> Also, is it a way to check, if my flag was reviewed by moderator, who it was reviewed by, and the result of the review?

No, there isn't a way to tell who reviewed a flag, though in your flagging summary page (linked from your profile page next to "helpful flags", if you ever flagged), there are statistics that tell you the result of each flag.

Comment: I've updated the question to include problems with reopen review queue, could you suggest smth?

Comment: @PavelK - You can see whether a suggested edit was approved by looking at your profile page under Activity -> Suggestions and clicking on the specific suggestion. As for the reopening - you don't currently have the reputation to view the details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Oded. My edit was accepted, but it still a little embarrassing not to be able to track any progress or changes according to this edit because I have not enough reputation... Maybe it would be better to give such an opportunity, how do you think?

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, that is fine.

A question often does not get much attention after being put *on-hold*. Most of the questions would not get the enough users that could flag/vote to reopened after being edited.

You can see if a moderator handled your flag and with what outcome by clicking on the *helpful flags* link in your profile. The status of a flag will be

- active (not handled yet)
- helpful
- declined

Comment: I've flagged the question but in my profile info in *stats* section there is only *profile views*, no *helpful flags*. Am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: We would prefer that you not flag for moderator attention, but let the review queue handle it.

Comment: Ok, but I'm still a little embarrassed not to be able to track any progress or changes according to my edit because I have not enough reputation...